# How to create robot framework test library using java + maven

Tags: java, robotframework

I want to develop java libray using org.robotframework(2.8.4) and maven.

My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

I want my custom script file follow format (without add classpath)

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar %*
```

How can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must create file main of Robot framework like:

```
    import org.robotframework.RobotFramework;

    public class RobotFrameworkTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            prepareYourEnvironmentTest();
            RobotFramework.main(args);
        }
        private static void prepareYourEnvironmentTest() {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

In pom.xml file you must use maven shade plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>ors.robotframework.RobotFrameworkTest</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Great work!
I use spring framework to create robot test lib. It works! Thanks